# accessing object that is creating from a form submission

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am in the process of learning angular. I've created a simple HTML form and want that submission to create an object that I can access in other tables.

Code from 1 row of the HTML table/form

```
            <tr>

                <td>Q1</td>
                <td><input type="number" ng-model="stateAid.WADM_Q1" placeholder="0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="stateAid.Foundation_Aid_Q1" placeholder="$0.00" class="currency"></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="stateAid.Salary_Q1" class="currency" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="stateAid.Transport_Q1" class="currency" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td> {{ final_total_Q1 | currency }} </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
```

Angular Code:

```
app.controller('StateAidTable',function($scope) {

$scope.master={};

$scope.update =function(stateaid){


    $scope.master = angular.copy(stateaid);
    $scope.WADM_q1 = stateaid.WADM_Q1;

};
```

since the stateaid object has been copied to the $scope.master, does that mean that the master is now the object that I use to access the object's properties in the template. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No this way you cannot make a copy of an object. It depends upon how you are calling the update function and where you calling and what parameters you are passing through it in the html. Can you attach a plnkr or fiddle for the working code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Tcurran4589/dgoxnuhk/3/

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms  - used this as a starting place

Comment: I attached a plnkr in the answer working absolutely fine. I hope i was able to help you.

Comment: Thanks so much, huge help!

Comment: Can you vote up and accept tag to my post below thank you so much for your vote and acceptance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Working absolutely fine link for the solution i have performed it for Q1, you can do it similarly for rest of them: http://plnkr.co/edit/Aabu35evC5GVhfuVLOHA?p=preview

```
 $scope.update = function(stateaid) {

            debugger
            console.log($scope.stateAid.Foundation_Aid_Q1);

     $scope.final_total_Q1=parseInt($scope.stateAid.Foundation_Aid_Q1+$scope.stateAid.Salary_Q1+$scope.stateAid.Transprot_Q1);
     console.log($scope.final_total_Q1)
        $scope.master = angular.copy(stateaid);
        return $scope.master;
      };
```